# A problem about SurfaceView regarding game animation

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an animation and this animation must work using a moving object (my object class).

My problem is that when I pause the app the animation starts all over again after I resumed my app . . .

I will use this animation for my 2D game... and here's the code:

The Object Class:

```
     private boolean enabled; 
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(); 
 
    public Object() { 
    stylePaint(paint); 
    } 
 
    public abstract void draw(Canvas var1); 
 
    public Paint getPaint() { 
    return paint; 
    } 
 
    public boolean isEnabled() { 
        return enabled; 
    } 
 
    public void setEnabled(boolean bl) { 
        enabled = bl; 
    } 
 
    public abstract void stylePaint(Paint var1);
```

The Class that I used which extends my Object Class:

```
private Point pos;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Context context;
private int height, width, visibility;
private static int vheight, vwidth;
private static View view;
public static final int
VISIBLE = 255,
INVISIBLE = 0;
 public static final int
dirAll = -5,
dirX = -1,
dirY = -2,
ndirAll = -6,
ndirX = -3,
ndirY = -4;
 
private int speed; 

public Actor(int x, int y) {
pos = new Point(x, y);
if(getSyncedView() != null) context = getSyncedView().getContext();
}

public Actor(int x, int y, int w, int h) { 
this(x, y);
setDimensions(w, h);
}

public int getWidth() {
return width;
}

public static void syncView(View v) {
view = v;
vheight = v.getHeight();
vwidth = v.getWidth();
}

public static View getSyncedView() {
return view;
}

public void setPadding(int x, int y) {
setDimensions(getX() + x, getY() + y);
}

public void setGravity(Gravity where) { // Gravity is an enum
if(view != null) {
final int
n = vwidth - width,
n2 = vheight - height,
n3 = n / 2,
n4 = n2 / 2;
switch (where) {

  case CENTER: {
  setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
  break;
  }
  
  case CENTER_HORIZONTAL: {
  setX(n3);
  break;
  }
  
  case CENTER_VERTICAL: {
  setY(n4);
  break;
  }
  
  case LEFT: {
  setX(0);
  break;
  }
  
  case RIGHT: {
  setX(n);
  break;
  }
  
  case TOP: {
  setY(0);
  break;
  }
  
  case BOTTOM: {
  setY(n2);
  break;
  }
  
  default: {
  break;
  }
  }
  }
}

public int getHeight() {
return height;
}

public void setDimensions(int w, int h) {
width = w;
height = h;
}

public Point getPoint() {
return pos;
}

public Rect getRect() {
Rect rect = new Rect();
getRectF().round(rect);
return rect;
}

public RectF getRectF() {
return new RectF(getX(), getY(), getX() + width, getY() + height);
}

public void setPos(int x, int y) {
pos = new Point(x, y);
}

public void setVisibility(int visible) {
getPaint().setAlpha(visible);
}

public int getVisibility() {
return visibility;
}

public void alignTo(PositionedObject target, Gravity where) {
//Aligning this to target
if(view != null) {
int n = target.getX(),
   n2 = (target.getWidth() - getWidth()) / 2,
   n3 = (target.getWidth() + getWidth()) / 2,
   n4 = target.getY(),
   n5 = (target.getHeight() - getHeight()) / 2,
   n6 = (target.getHeight() + getHeight()) / 2;

switch (where) {

case CENTER: {
setX(n + n2);
setY(n4 + n5);
break;
}

case BOTTOM: {
setX(n + n2);
setY(n4 + n5 + n6);
break;
}

case TOP: {
setX(n + n2);
setY(n4 + n5 - n6);
break;
}

case LEFT: {
setX(n + n2 - n3);
setY(n4 + n5);
break;
}

case RIGHT: {
setX(n + n2 + n3);
setY(n4 + n5);
break;
}

default: break;
  }
 }
}

public int getX() {
return pos.x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
pos.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
return pos.y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
pos.y = y;
}

public boolean intersect(MovingObject mo) {
return getRect().intersect(mo.getRect());

 public int getSpeed() { 
return speed; 
} 
 
public void move(int where) {

if (isEnabled()) {
switch (where) {

case dirX: { 
getPoint().x = getPoint().x + getSpeed(); 
break; 
}

case ndirX: { 
getPoint().x = getPoint().x - getSpeed(); 
break; 
}

case dirY: { 
getPoint().y = getPoint().y + getSpeed(); 
break; 
}

case ndirY: { 
getPoint().y = getPoint().y - getSpeed(); 
break; 
}

case dirAll: { 
move(dirX); 
move(dirY); 
break; 
}

case ndirAll: { 
move(ndirX); 
move(ndirY); 
break; 
}

}
}

} 
 
public void setSpeed(int sp) { 
speed = sp;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), getX(), getY(), getPaint());
}

@Override
public void stylePaint(Paint p) {
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
bitmap = bm;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
return bitmap;
}

Bitmap a(Bitmap bm) {
setBitmap(bm);
setDimensions(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
return getBitmap();
}

public Bitmap createFromAsset(String path) {
try {
return a(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(path)));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}


public Bitmap createFromRes(int drawable) {
return a(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawable));
}
```

My SurfaceView:

```
public SharedPreferences pref;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private final Paint paint = new Paint(); 
private BaseThread thread;
private Thread thread2;
private int panelColor; 
public Actor cmd, actor, actor2; // The class that extends my object class.

public AbstractPanel(Context context) { 
super(context);
init(context);
}

public AbstractPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
init(context);
}

void init(Context context) {
SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
thread = new BaseThread(holder);
pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Scene", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
holder.addCallback(this);
panelColor = Color.BLACK;
}

protected BaseThread getLoop() { 
return thread;
} 
 
protected Paint getPaint() { 
return paint; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int var1, KeyEvent var2) {
return true;
}
 
public void onStart() {
PositionedObject.syncView(this);

cmd = new Actor(0, 0);
actor = new Actor(0, 0);
actor2 = new Actor(0, 0);

cmd.createFromAsset("cmd.png");

actor.createFromAsset("grandGL.png");
actor2.createFromAsset("presents.png");

actor.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
actor2.alignTo(actor, Gravity.BOTTOM);

actor.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
actor2.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
cmd.setSpeed(1);
cmd.setEnabled(true);
}

public void onTimer() {}
 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
return true; 
} 

public void redrawCanvas(Canvas canvas) { 
actor.draw(canvas); 
actor2.draw(canvas);
cmd.draw(canvas);

cmd.move(Actor.dirX);
switch (cmd.getX()) {

default : break;

case 25: {
actor.setVisibility(30);
break;
}

case 26: {
actor.setVisibility(60);
break;
}

case 27: {
actor.setVisibility(90);
break;
}

case 28: {
actor.setVisibility(120);
break;
}

case 29: {
actor.setVisibility(150);
break;
}

case 30: {
actor.setVisibility(180);
break;
}

case 31: {
actor.setVisibility(210);
break;
}

case 32: {
actor.setVisibility(240);
break;
}

case 35: {
actor.setVisibility(Actor.VISIBLE);
break;
}

case 60: {
actor2.setVisibility(Actor.VISIBLE);
break;
  }

case 130: {
actor.setVisibility(210);
actor2.setVisibility(210);
break;
}

case 132: {
actor.setVisibility(190);
actor2.setVisibility(190);
break;
}

case 134: {
actor.setVisibility(160);
actor2.setVisibility(160);
break;
}

case 136: {
actor.setVisibility(130);
actor2.setVisibility(130);
break;
}

case 138: {
actor.setVisibility(100);
actor2.setVisibility(100);
break;
}

case 140: {
actor.setVisibility(60);
actor2.setVisibility(60);
break;
}

case 142: {
actor.setVisibility(30);
actor2.setVisibility(30);
break;
}

case 146: {
actor.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
actor2.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
break;
}
 
 }
}

@Override 
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
super.draw(canvas);
canvas.drawColor(panelColor); 
redrawCanvas(canvas); 
} 
 
public void setPanelColor(int n) { 
panelColor = n; 
} 
 
public void startGameLoop() {
thread.setRunning(true);
} 
 
public void stopGameLoop() {
thread.setRunning(false);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder hol, int n, int w, int h) { 
} 
 
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
thread2 = new Thread(thread);
thread2.setPriority(1); 
startGameLoop();
thread2.start();
onStart();
} 
 
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
stopGameLoop();
}

public class BaseThread implements Runnable {

private SurfaceHolder surHol;
private boolean running;

public BaseThread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
surHol = holder;
}

public void delay(long l) {
try {
Thread.sleep(l);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

public boolean isRunning() {
return running;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
synchronized (this) {
running = run;
 }
}

@Override 
public void run() { 
synchronized (surHol) {
delay(800L);
while (isRunning()) {
Canvas canvas = null;
try {
canvas = surHol.lockCanvas();
synchronized (canvas) {
onTimer();
draw(canvas);
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
if (canvas != null) {
surHol.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
delay(36L);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I also need simplifications for my codes . . . Thanks in advance for the help . . .

I only accept codes using SurfaceView because this is for my game . . .

**SOLVED**

Here' s the final code and it's free to copy . . .

I've found out that some onStart() methods must be at the constructor since onStart() method is always called after resuming so I created an onCreate() method to put some codes of onStart() . . .

For LCPanel that extends AbstractPanel that extends SurfaceView:

```
Actor
cmd,
actor,
actor2; 

public LCPanel(Context context) { 
super(context);
}
 
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int n, KeyEvent keyEvent) { 
return true; 
} 

@Override
public void onCreate() {

cmd = new Actor(0, 0);
actor = new Actor(0, 0);
actor2 = new Actor(0, 0);

cmd.createFromAsset("cmd.png");
actor.createFromAsset("grandGL.png");
actor2.createFromAsset("presents.png");
}

@Override 
public void onStart() {
actor.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
actor2.alignTo(actor, Gravity.BOTTOM);

actor.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
actor2.setVisibility(Actor.INVISIBLE);
cmd.setSpeed(1);
cmd.setEnabled(true);
}
 
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
return true; 
} 

/* package */ final int a (int n, int n2) {
return (30 * (n - n2)) > 255 ? 255 : 30 * (n - n2); // alpha animator
}

@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
int n = cmd.getX();
actor.draw(canvas); 
actor2.draw(canvas);
cmd.draw(canvas);
cmd.move(Actor.dirX);

if (n >= 25 && n <= 38) actor.setVisibility(a(n, 25));

if(n >= 38 && n <= 145) {
actor.setVisibility(Actor.VISIBLE);
if (n >= 74) actor2.setVisibility(Actor.VISIBLE);
}

if (n >= 145 && n <= 162) {
int n3 = 255 - a(n, 145);
actor.setVisibility(n3);
actor2.setVisibility(n3);
actor.shrink();
}

if (n >= 163) {
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
actor2.draw(canvas);
actor2.createFromAsset("loadin.png");
actor2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
actor2.setVisibility(Actor.VISIBLE);
}

}
```

Edit some existing AbstractPanel methods:

```
public AbstractPanel(Context context) { 
super(context);
init(context);
}

public AbstractPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
init(context);
}

void init(Context context) {
pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Scene", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
getHolder().addCallback(this);
Actor.syncView(this);
onCreate();
}

public abstract void onStart();
 
public abstract void onCreate();

public abstract void onDraw(Canvas canvas);
```

Edit the thread inside the AbstractClass:

```
public class BaseThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder surHol;
private boolean running;

public BaseThread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
super();
surHol = holder;
}
 
public void delay(long l) {
try { sleep(l); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
running = run;
}

@Override 
public synchronized void run() {
delay(800L);
onStart();
while (true) {
if (!running) break;
Canvas canvas = null;
try {
   canvas = surHol.lockCanvas();
   synchronized (canvas) {
   draw(canvas);
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
if (canvas != null) {
surHol.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
delay(36L);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And done, problem solved..! The animation must work properly as expected . . .